# list_head: get garbage if start parsing from second element

Tags: c, linux, list, linked-list, garbage

I'm using in my C project list_head structure to define a linked_list. In some conditions I need to parse the list from the second element, but in this case I get an additional element with a garbage value. I tried with a small program in my pc to simulate the same scenario. I get the same issue:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"

struct struct_report{
        struct list_head list;
        char *report;
};


//Add an element to the linked list
void add_report_to_list(struct list_head *reports, char *report) {
        struct struct_report *report_strct;
        report_strct = calloc(1, sizeof(struct struct_report));
        list_add_tail(&report_strct->list, reports);
        report_strct->report= strdup(report);
}

int main() {
        struct struct_report *retreport;
        LIST_HEAD(reports); //instantiate a struct list_head instance
        add_report_to_list(&reports, "elt1");
        add_report_to_list(&reports, "elt2");
        add_report_to_list(&reports, "elt3");
        add_report_to_list(&reports, "elt4");
        list_for_each_entry(retreport, &reports, list){
                printf("============> no next retreport: %s\n", retreport->report);
        }
        printf("\n");
        list_for_each_entry(retreport, reports.next, list){
                printf("============> Next retreport: %s\n", retreport->report);
        }
        return 1;
}
```

list.h is the same of linux: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h

I get as an execution result the following trace:

```
============> no next retreport: elt1
============> no next retreport: elt2
============> no next retreport: elt3
============> no next retreport: elt4

============> Next retreport: elt2
============> Next retreport: elt3
============> Next retreport: elt4
============> Next retreport:
```

It's clear that in the case I start parsing normally from the first element I don't have any problem. But in the case I start from the second element in the list I get an additional one with strange value like garbage.

Has some an explanation why I get an additional element? And how I can fix it to parse until elt4?

Comment: What is `LIST_HEAD(reports);`? The `.next` field is not defined anywhere. What is `list_for_each_entry()`? The part`list_for_each_entry(...){ printf ... } looks strange.  Please [edit] your question to add this information instead of adding a comment.

Comment: Please show definitions for `list_for_each_entry` function and `struct list_head` structure

Comment: @Bodo LIST_HEAD(reports); instantiates a struct list_head rports variable.
.next is an attribute in list_head:
struct list_head{struct list_head *next; struct list_head *prev;};

Comment: @RishikeshRaje https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h

Comment: @KallelOmar Please [edit] your question and add all information to the question instead of writing comments.

Comment: I have just updated the question with reference to list.h used

Comment: I am not saying that this is a problem but it's a good tactic to set to NULL every pointer that you declare.I would do struct struct_report *retreport = NULL

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis: thank you for your suggestion. I instantiated retreport with NULL value but the issue is not fixed.

Comment: I wonder why this bad question is up-voted?!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I can't what's wrong in my question. Please if there's an issue please tell me or edit it.

Comment: @KallelOmar You was already pointed out why your question is very bad.

Comment: @KallelOmar Please do not put tags into the question title — *that’s what tags are for.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start from the first element of the list (and not from the head) then the `list_for_each_entry()` will stop in the same list object because it's a circular list.

So the `list_for_each_entry()` will go through the head. And the head is not attached to an entry. so when you try to refer to the entry from the head list then you will get garbage

Solution: start the loop from the head of the list and skip the first element

Answer (score 1):

The list implementation actually creates a ring. The list head is a dummy element which points `next` to the first element and `prev` to the last element. (Initially both point to the list head itself.)  Adding an element at the tail is actually implemented as adding it "before the list head". When looping over this ring, the head is marked by a separate pointer pointing to it. There is no other way to distinguish it from the other elements of the list.

The `for` loop in `list_for_each_entry` has a comparison with the `head` pointer as the loop condition, so it will stop when it would reach the object supplied as the list head again.

```
/**
 * list_for_each_entry  -   iterate over list of given type
 * @pos:    the type * to use as a loop cursor.
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 * @member: the name of the list_head within the struct.
 */
#define list_for_each_entry(pos, head, member)              \
    for (pos = list_first_entry(head, typeof(*pos), member);    \
         &pos->member != (head);                    \
         pos = list_next_entry(pos, member))
```

Both macros `list_first_entry` and `list_next_entry` return a pointer to a user defined structure that is supposed to contain a `struct list_head` by using a macro `container_of`.

If you pass `reports.next` instead of `&reports` to `list_for_each_entry()`, it will take this as the dummy list head element and regard all other elements in the ring as real list entries.

Your code prints garbage for the element behind the tail element because this is a pure `struct list_head` which is not embedded in a `struct struct_report`, so the macro `list_next_entry` returns a pointer to the memory before your `struct list_head reports` in `main()` which is undefined behavior.

If your program does not crash, you would get the same garbage after `elt4` if you would pass e.g. `reports.next->next`. In this case I would expect output like this:

```
============> Next retreport: elt3
============> Next retreport: elt4
============> Next retreport: <garbage>
============> Next retreport: elt1
```

Answer (score 0):

While the same type - `list_head` - is used for both:

- list head,
- list elements,

they are **not interchangeable**. If some macro expects *list head* as an argument, you need to provide **exactly** pointer to the *list head*, not a pointer to a *list element*.

Macro `list_for_each_entry` accepts pointer to the *list head* as the second argument, so one shouldn't pass pointer to the element instead.

For skip first elements when iterating over list, macros

- `list_for_each_entry_from`
- `list_for_each_entry_continue` or

could be used.

Both these macros take the same arguments as `list_for_each_entry` one, but they take into accound initial value of the cursor (the first argument):

- `list_for_each_entry_from` starts iteration **at** the element pointed by cursor,
- `list_for_each_entry_continue` starts iteration **after** the element pointed by cursor.

So, iterating over list with skipping the first element could be follows:

```
// Set cursor to the first element in the list
retreport = list_first_entry(reports, typeof(*retreport), list);
// Iterate starting after the cursor
list_for_each_entry_continue(retreport, reports, list){
    printf("============> Next retreport: %s\n", retreport->report);
}
```